# How to get JavaScript generated content when parsing page with Jsoup

Tags: javascript

[I want to get this value selected in the picture 1, but it's generated after one second of the page loading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Sf9a.png)

[This is what I actually get when I use jsoup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/444Si.png)

```
String form_build_id =newAppDoc.select("input[name=form_build_id]").first().attr("value");  
System.out.println(form_build_id);

String form_token = newAppDoc.select("input[name=form_token]").first().attr("value"); 
System.out.println(form_token);

String form_id = newAppDoc.select("input[name=form_id]").first().attr("value"); 
System.out.println(form_id);`][2]
```

any ideas please.

Comment: Are you talking about Java or Javascript ? Moreover your question has a really poor formating, please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51022248/how-to-get-javascript-generated-content-when-parsing-page-with-jsoup#) it to make it easier to read. Then improve the presentation of your problem, that's not clear what you are asking for

Comment: thanks for your response,sorry i can't speak English very well,so i want to get a html page content with java using jsoup, but when i get this page i found that an element that a want to extract and use his value is missing, so when i get to developer mode in the bowser his value appear after one second when the page is finish loading, you can see the difference in picture 1 and 2.